# How to fire a remote event when a part is touched (Roblox Studio)

Tags: events, lua, game-engine, roblox

I'm trying to make it so when you touch a block in roblox studio it fires a remote event that tells A Gui that it can show up and tell the player they are touching the block. Here is the server script.

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

function partTouched(obj)

    if obj.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid") and obj.Parent.Name ~= "NextBot" then
        print(obj.Parent) -- prints my username
        local player = obj.Parent
        ReplicatedStorage.Insafety:FireClient(player)
        
    else
        print("Not alive... :(")
    end
 end


script.Parent.Touched:connect(partTouched)
```

but every time it throws up the error `FireClient: player argument must be a Player object  -  Server - Safezone:7`
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that when you call `Insafety:FireClient(player)`, the `player` object is not a Player.

You are mistaking the player's [Character model](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#Character) (the thing that runs around the game world) for the [Player](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player) object itself (the object that represents the Roblox player that joined the game).

Try using the [Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetPlayerFromCharacter) function to easily get the Player from the character model in a Touched event :

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

function partTouched(obj)
    -- escape if NextBot touches this
    if obj.Parent.Name == "NextBot" then
        return
    end

    -- Check if a player has touched the part
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(obj.Parent)
    if player then
        -- fire the event to the player that touched the part
        ReplicatedStorage.Insafety:FireClient(player)
    end
 end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(partTouched)
```